# Does the "exports" attributes in package.json work in workspaces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-workspaces

I have a npm package set up as follows

```
project
|
|-- package.json
|
|-- workspace_a
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- index.js
|
|-- workspace_b
|   |-- package.json
|   |
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- index.js
|   |   |
|   |   |-- folder_1
|   |   |   |-- index.js
|   |   |
|   |   |-- folder_2
|   |       |-- index.js
|   |
|   |-- dist
|       |-- index.js
|       |
|       |-- folder_1
|       |   |-- index.js
|       |
|       |-- folder_2
|           |-- index.js
```

The main project file is propery configured for workspaces, as are the workspace project.json files.

project/workspace_b/package.json contains the following:

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
   "exports: {
     ".": "./dist/index.js",
     "./*": "./dist/*/*.js"
    }
}
```

project/workspace_a/index.js:

```
import example from "@project/workspace_b/folder_1"
```

I am expecting this line to load the default export contained in `project/workspace_b/dist/folder_1/index.js` however I am recieving the error `Cannot find module: '@project/workspace_b/folder_1'`

Should the exports attributes in `project/workspace_b/package.json` handle this for me?

Comment: 18 months on and I just stumbled across this looking for the same answer. I need to export browser and node versions of my module that's in a monorepo and I am not filled with hope. Nobody has been able to answer this yet?